# Inequality involving the regression function and its approximation

Tags: regression, classification

In the proof of Theorem 2.2 from the book by [Devroye et al.](http://www.szit.bme.hu/~gyorfi/pbook.pdf), I don't understand why $g(x) \ne g^*(x)$ implies $|\eta(x) - \tilde\eta(x)| \geq |\eta(x) - \dfrac{1}{2}|$.

Note that $\eta(x) = \mathbb{E}\{Y|X=x\}$ is the regression function, $\tilde\eta(x)$ is an approximation of $\eta(x)$, $g^*(x)$ is the Bayes classifier
$$ g^*(x) =
  \begin{cases}
   0 & \text{if } \eta(x)\leq\dfrac{1}{2} \\
   1       & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}$$
and finally, $g(x)$ is defined like $g^*(x)$ with $\tilde\eta(x)$ replacing $\eta(x)$.

Comment: The defintion of $g^*$ you are giving does not coincide with the defintion of the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It follows by checking each case.

Given that $g(x)\neq g^*(x)$, we have that:

(i) If $g^*(x)=0 \Rightarrow \eta(x)\leq \dfrac{1}{2}$ and $g(x)=1$ which is equivalent to $\tilde\eta(x)>\dfrac{1}{2}$. Therefore

$$\vert \eta(x) - \tilde\eta(x)\vert =  \tilde\eta(x) -  \eta(x) \geq  \dfrac{1}{2}- \eta(x) = \vert \eta(x) - \dfrac{1}{2}\vert  .$$

(ii) If $g^*(x)=1 \Rightarrow \eta(x)> \dfrac{1}{2}$ and $g(x)=0$ which is equivalent to $\tilde\eta(x)\leq\dfrac{1}{2}$. Therefore

$$\vert \eta(x) - \tilde\eta(x)\vert =  \eta(x) - \tilde\eta(x) \geq  \eta(x) - \dfrac{1}{2} = \vert \eta(x) - \dfrac{1}{2}\vert  .$$

I hope this helps.